# Is there a way to export a MySQL database to an SQL file without ruining foreign key dependencies?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a large database schema with over 170 tables, many of which depends upon others.  For example, `customers` and `employees` both have a `person_id` which refers to a record in the `people` table.

I want to be able to generate a `baseline.sql` file which creates all these tables, with default values populated.  I simply exported an existing database with everything properly formatted, but because the resulting `baseline.sql` file simply generates the tables in *alphabetical order* I end up with issues like `customers` and `employees` pointing to `people` who don't exist yet (because `C<E<P`, alphabetically).

**Is there a way to export the database while considering the necessary table creation and population order?**

I know foreign keys can be recursive or otherwise cause problems, but given my dataset does not have instances of these and the likely commonhood of this problem, I feel like there might be something easy out there before I reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the beginning of your sql file:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

And add this to the end:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```